Dual lattice and non-degenerate bilinear form over modules
In my class, we talked about lattices. We took $A$ to be an integral domain, $K$ its field of fractions, $V$ a finite dimensional $K$-vector space, $M$ a module over $A$ contained in $V$, and we said $M$ to be a full lattice if it is finitely generated as an $A$-module and generates $V$ as a $K$-vector space. Then, given a non-degenerate bilinear form $f(\cdot,\cdot)$ on $M$ (i.e. $f$ gives an isomorphism from $M$ to its dual), we defined the dual lattice $M^\star$ as the set of $v\in V$ s.t. $f(v,m)\in A$ for each $m\in M$. But is the dual lattice a lattice itself?
I've seen an example for integer lattices in real vector spaces using the Euclidean inner product, where the idea is to use a dual basis because the form has an invertible matrix, but can I say here that the matrix with coefficients in a ring is invertible? Wikipedia says a little about unimodular forms without references.

It might not be invertible over $A$, but you can consider the same matrix over $K$.
